# Read numerical values with a regular expression and define them

Tags: python, regex

I am in this situation, I have a string like this:

```
Values_dict = 'a=0.67,loc=-0.02,scale=0.08'
```

I would like to read numerical values. The "loc" and "scale" values are present in all the strings I read. While in addition to the value 'a' there may be others. I call these other values "arg".

To do this, I improvised a regular expression. I hope someone more experienced can help me rewrite it better.

```
p = re.compile(r'\d+\.\d+|-\d+\.\d+')
Values_dict = tuple([float(i) for i in p.findall(Values_dict)])  
arg = Values_dict[:-2]
loc = Values_dict[-2]
scale = Values_dict[-1]
```

Unfortunately, I get this result in the output. And I don't understand how this is possible

```
arg
Out[221]: (0.67,)

loc
Out[222]: -0.02

scale
Out[223]: 0.08
```

I would not like there to be a parenthesis and comma in the first number

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure there are always three matches in the string, all you need is get the first item, `Values_dict[0]`, or the third item from the end, `Values_dict[-3]`.

However, you may parse the whole string with

```py
import re
p = re.compile(r'(\w+)=(-?\d*\.?\d+)')
Values_dict = 'a=0.67,loc=-0.02,scale=0.08'
result = dict(p.findall(Values_dict))
print( result )
# => {'a': '0.67', 'loc': '-0.02', 'scale': '0.08'}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tdzhs8/2) and the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/6PXdvA).

*Details*:

- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `=` - an equals sign
- `(-?\d*\.?\d+)` - Group 2: an optional `-`,  zero or more digits, an optional dot and one or more digits.